# Simple bitwise manipulation for little-endian integer, in big-endian machine?

Tags: c, binary, integer, bit-manipulation, endianness

For a specific need I am building a four byte integer out of four one byte chars, using nothing too special (on my little endian platform):

```
    return (( v1 << 24) | (v2 << 16) | (v3 << 8) | v4);
```

I am aware that an integer stored in a big endian machine would look like `AB BC CD DE` instead of `DE CD BC AB` of little endianness, although would it affect the my operation completely in that I will be shifting incorrectly, or will it just cause a correct result that is stored in reverse and needs to be reversed?

I was wondering whether to create a second version of this function to do (yet unknown) bit manipulation for a big-endian machine, or possibly to use ntonl related function which I am unclear of how that would know if my number is in correct order or not.

What would be your suggestion to ensure compatibility, keeping in mind I do need to form integers in this manner?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you are working at the *value* level, there will be absolutely no difference in the results you obtain regardless of whether your machine is little-endian or big-endian. I.e. as long as you are using language-level operators (like `|` and `<<` in your example), you will get exactly the same arithmetical result from the above expression on any platform. The endianness of the machine is not detectable and not visible at this level.

The only situations when you need to care about endianness is when the data you are working with is examined at the *object representation* level, i.e. in situations when its raw memory representation is important. What you said above about "`AB BC CD DE` instead of `DE CD BC AB`" is specifically about the raw memory layout of the data. That's what functions like `ntonl` do: they convert one memory layout to another memory layout. So far you gave no indication that the actual raw memory layout is in any way important to you. Is it?

Again, if you only care about the *value* of the above expression, it is fully and totally endianness-independent. Basically, you are not supposed to care about endianness at all when you write C programs that don't attempt to access and examine the raw memory contents.

Comment: This confirms what I once thought originally, in that conversion would be redundant as it has not stored yet. Thank you.

Comment: The reason for this is because registers aren't generally considered one endianness or another. Nearly every (all?) architecture, even little-endian ones like x86, make the far left bit of the register the MSB and the far right the LSB (left and right being defined as the direction bits move for a shift left or shift right).

Comment: I very much appreciate what you have put in to your input. This  answers all I've needed to know about the subject, and even what to (not) care about when writing functions like these.

Answer (score 3):

> although would it affect the my operation completely in that I will be shifting incorrectly (?)

No.

The result will be the same regardless of the endian architecture. Bit shifting and twiddling are just like regular arithmetic operations. Is `2 + 2` the same on little endian and big endian architectures? Of course. `2 << 2` would be the same as well.

Little and big endian problems arise when you are dealing directly with the memory. You will run into problems when you do the following:

```
char bytes[] = {1, 0, 0, 0};
int n = *(int*)bytes;
```

On little endian machines, n will equal 0x00000001. On big endian machines, n will equal 0x01000000. This is when you will have to swap the bytes around.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, I'd always thought that shifting left would shift the integer in memory (visualizing it leaving extra zeros after it for others to fill), rather than just multiply it by powers of two and adding the other numbers in to specific spots.

Answer (score 1):

[Rewritten for clarity]

`ntohl` (and `ntohs`, etc.) is used primarily for moving data from one machine to another. If you're simply manipulating data on one machine, then it's perfectly fine to do bit-shifting without any further ceremony -- bit-shifting (at least in C and C++) is defined in terms of multiplying/dividing by powers of 2, so it works the same whether the machine is big-endian or little-endian.

When/if you need to (at least potentially) move data from one machine to another, it's typically sensible to use `htonl` before you send it, and `ntohl` when you receive it. This may be entirely nops (in the case of BE to BE), two identical transformations that cancel each other out (LE to LE), or actually result in swapping bytes around (LE to BE or vice versa).

Comment: Thank you for the rewritten clarification! +1

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I think a lot of what has been said here is correct.  However, if the programmer has coded with endianness in mind, say using masks for bitwise inspection and manipulation, then cross-platform results could be unexpected.

You can determine 'endianness' at runtime as follows:

```
#define LITTLE_ENDIAN 0
#define BIG_ENDIAN    1

int endian() {
    int i = 1;
    char *p = (char *)&i;

    if (p[0] == 1)
        return LITTLE_ENDIAN;
    else
        return BIG_ENDIAN;
}
```

... and proceed accordingly.

I borrowed the code snippet from here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/index.html?ca=drs-  where there is also an excellent discussion of these issues.

hth -

Perry