# Bit manipulation of integers depending on endianess

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, endianness

My question concerns bit manipulation when the endianess changes. In particular I have some code that reads individual bits of a `uint32_t` value and performs bit manipulation on them. The purpose was UTF-8 encoding. It works perfectly for my little endian machine.

Revisiting the code recently it dawned on me that I was not considering endianess of the machine as far as the `uint32_t` value's bit representation is concerned. So I have some questions regarding that respect.

Let's assume an example code that just requires bits 7-10 of an `uint32_t` saved in a different byte.

```
uint32_t v;
v = 18341;
char c = (v &(uint32_t) 0x3C0)>>6;
```

For little endian the number 18341 is represented as `0x47A5`  or in binary:

0100 01**11 10**10 0101

and the above code should give us 1110 stored in the char

Now the question is how would we achieve this in a Big Endian machine? The same number would be represented quite differently `0xA5470000` or in binary:

**10**10 0101 0100 01**11** 0000 0000 0000 0000

with the bits we seek being in totally different positions and not even consequent.

Instead of using `0x3C0` at the other side of **&** we would have to use something else
since the byte order is different. And especially since we need consequent bits of a byte we would require multiple boolean **&** operations like below right?

```
char c = ((v&(uint32_t)0xc0)>>6) | ((v&(uint32_t)0x300)>>6)
```

Summing up. Is my understanding correct that in the cases where we need to get sequential bits of an integer value represented in binary we would need to perform different manipulations for the two endianess cases?

Finally is there a better way to achieve the same thing than the one I showed above? Maybe I am missing something totally obvious.

Comment: Endianness is only relevant when reinterpreting a piece of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you are using values (like 0x300) and language operators (<<, |, &) it does not matter because the value will be represented according to the machine. So in your case you do not need to worry about this problem. You should worry, for example, when you are copying bytes from file into the memory.

If you are dealing with the memory representation directly, you can convert the representation before manipulation:

```
#if defined (BENDIAN)
   val = makelittle(val);
#endif
   manip_lendian(val);
#if defined (BENDIAN)
   val = makebig(val);
#endif
```

Also [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5643008/390913)

Comment: Yes ofcourse I can and maybe this is a nice way to just get over a big headache, but what if I actually attempt the manipulation with big endian as a different function as shown above? Is this how it should work?

Basically my question is like that, since I don't have a big endian machine currently available and can't test the code I wrote above.

Comment: Hmm I am a bit confused. 
0x300 as a value is represented differently in different endianess machines, right? And >> or << would shift bits of different representations so the outcome should not be the same, right?

Comment: yes, you will see no difference in your results. You should not worry about representation for these operations.

Comment: Hmm your linked answer seems to suggest that indeed there is no difference. If I understand correctly the answer suggests that there is no point to do anything like what I posted in the Big Endian case in my question, since the language itself makes sure they remain consistent. 

That's a huge headache off my head right there.

Comment: Endian only matters when storing or loading values from memory.