# Bitwise operation on big endian and little endian differences

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm sorting the "children" of prefixes for IP address space. For example, 8.8.8.0/24 is the child of 8.8.8.0/23 in IP address space. I'm confused as to why the following two operations provide different results on my x86 little endian system

A little background information:
A /24 means that the first 24 bits of a 32 bit IPv4 address are "defined". That means that 8.8.8.0/24 encompasses 8.8.8.0 - 8.8.8.255. Similarly, for every bit that's not defined, the amount of address space doubles. 8.8.8.0/23 would have only the first 23 bits defined, so the actual address space goes from 8.8.8.0 - 8.8.9.255, or twice the size of a /24.

Now the confusion I'm having is with the following bitshifts

```
inet_addr("8.8.8.0") << (32 - 23) produces 269488128
inet_addr("8.8.9.0") << (32 - 23) produces 303042560
```

inet_addr produces a big endian number. However, when converting it to little endian -

```
htonl(inet_addr("8.8.8.0")) >> 9 produces 263172
htonl(inet_addr("8.8.9.0")) >> 9 produces 263172
```

Which is the expected result. Dropping the last 9 bits would mean that 8.8.9.0 would be equal to 8.8.8.0 in theory.

What am I missing here? Shouldn't it work the same for big endian?

Edit: Not a duplicate because I do understand the difference in how endianness affects the way numbers are stored, but I'm clearly missing something with these bitwise operators. The question is more to do with bitwise than endianness - the endianness is just there to foster an example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple bitwise manipulation for little-endian integer, in big-endian machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642981/simple-bitwise-manipulation-for-little-endian-integer-in-big-endian-machine)

Comment: Which of those 4 outputs was unexpected? What value did you expect?

Comment: The first two outputs were unexpected. I expected the first 2 outputs to be equal, just as the third and fourth outputs are equal

Comment: `htonl` doesn't reverse the bits; it reverses 8-bit units. In the first case, the differing bit is the 16th place from the left; in the second case the differing bit is the 9th place from the right

Comment: That would explain why, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86 is little endian. The number 1 in binary in little endian is

```
|10000000|00000000|00000000|00000000
```

If you bit shift this left by 9 bits it becomes...

```
|00000000|01000000|00000000|00000000
```

In a little endian machine 0xDEADBEEF printed out as a series of bytes from low to high address would actually print `EFBEADDE`, see

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4804/Basic-concepts-on-Endianness

and

https://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/Endianness.html.

Most people when thinking in binary think the number 1 is represented as follows (me included) and some people `think` this is big endian but it's not...

```
|00000000|00000000|00000000|00000001
```

In the code below I've printed out 0xDEADBEEF in little endian because my machine is an x86 and I've used the htonl function to convert it to network byte order. Note network byte order is defined as Big Endian.

So when I print out the big endian value for 1 ie `htonl(1)`. The big endian representation of `1` is

```
|00000000|00000000|00000000|10000000
```

Try this code

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void print_deadbeef(void *p, size_t bytes) {
  size_t i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < bytes; ++i) {
    printf("%02X", ((unsigned char*)p)[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void print_bin(uint64_t num, size_t bytes) {
  int i = 0;
  for(i = bytes * 8; i > 0; i--) {
    (i % 8 == 0) ? printf("|") : 1;
    (num & 1)    ? printf("1") : printf("0");
    num >>= 1;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
  in_addr_t left    = inet_addr("8.8.8.0");
  in_addr_t right   = inet_addr("8.8.9.0");
  in_addr_t left_h    = htonl(left);
  in_addr_t right_h   = htonl(right);
  in_addr_t left_s  = left  << 9;
  in_addr_t right_s = right >> 9;
  assert(left  != right);

  printf("left != right\n");
  print_bin(left, 4);
  print_bin(right, 4);
  printf("Big Endian if on x86\n");
  print_bin(left_s, 4);
  print_bin(right_s, 4);
  printf("Little Endian if on x86\n");
  print_bin(left_h, 4);
  print_bin(right_h, 4);

  printf("\n\nSome notes\n\n");

  printf("0xDEADBEEF printed on a little endian machine\n");
  uint32_t deadbeef = 0xDEADBEEF;
  print_deadbeef(&deadbeef, 4);

  uint32_t deadbeefBig = htonl(deadbeef);
  printf("\n0xDEADBEEF printed in network byte order (big endian)\n");
  print_deadbeef(&deadbeefBig, 4);

  printf("\n1 printed on a little endian machine\n");
  print_bin(1, 4);
  printf("\nhtonl(1) ie network byte order (big endian) on a little endian machine\n");
  print_bin(htonl(1), 4);

  return 0;
}
```

This is the output

```
left != right
|00010000|00010000|00010000|00000000
|00010000|00010000|10010000|00000000
Big Endian if on x86
|00000000|00001000|00001000|00001000
|00100001|00100000|00000000|00000000
Little Endian if on x86
|00000000|00010000|00010000|00010000
|00000000|10010000|00010000|00010000


Some notes

0xDEADBEEF printed on a little endian machine
EFBEADDE

0xDEADBEEF printed in network byte order (big endian)
DEADBEEF

1 printed on a little endian machine
|10000000|00000000|00000000|00000000

htonl(1) ie network byte order on a little endian machine
|00000000|00000000|00000000|10000000
```

Comment: It would really help if downvoters would explain why. I think the code shows exactly what's happening.

Comment: Harry go further into depth as to why this is the case.

Comment: I also thought it's a great answer (the code and the output practically say it all), although I'll add an answer with an explanation.

Comment: I'll add some depth to it to see if it helps. When it looks like the OP doesn't need hand holding I normally just post some code that demonstrates what's going on.

Comment: @Harry , I think your updated answer is providing some wrong information... From what I understand, the big endian vs. little endian ordering only refers to the bytes (not the bits). So `1`, in a single byte, is always `0b00000001`, no matter which endian system your using. The endian storage refers to the address space of the bytes (memory mapping), not the bits.

Comment: @Myst. Quoting the paper that introduced Endianness... `In a consistent order, the bit-order, the byte-order, the word-order, the page-order, and all the other higher level orders are all the same`. He defines this as Consistent Little Endian. Therefore if the lower addressed byte is on the left then bit 0 is also on the left. We write binary with the most significant bit on the left ie Inconsistent Little Endian if the lowest addressable byte was also on the left. x86 is in Consistent Little Endian format so if you write the lowest byte to the left then bit zero should be on the left as well.

Comment: " The big endian representation of 1 is
|00000000|00000000|00000000|10000000 "

Isn't this showing a big endian in terms of bytes, but little endian in terms of bits (since the least significant bit is first)?

Comment: @Myst I added some more notes on printing 0xDEADBEEF on a little endian machine and converting it back to big endian using htonl. I'm still not 100% comfortable with the answer though because htonl(170) does not match what I see in RFC1700.

Answer (score 1):

The question of Big Endian and Little Endian isn't really known to the machine.

The types in C don't contain such information since it's a Hardware issue, not a type related one.

The machine assumes that all multi-byte numbers are ordered according to it's local endian (on x86, this is usually little endian).

For this reason, bit shifting is always performed using the local endian assumption.

You can't correctly apply bit-shifting to a Big Endian number on a Little Endian machine.

You can't even print a Big Endian number to the screen on a Little Endian machine without getting a funny result.

This is why @Harry's answer was so cool, it prints out each bit, circumventing the issue.

Wikipedia has an [article about Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) with more details.

It should be noted that Endianness actually refers to the way a machine stores it's bytes in the memory.

For example, if the number were as String, Endianness would refer to the question: which "letter" (byte) would come first?

Some machine would store "Hello" and some would store "olleH" (for numbers only, in actual strings, the bytes are always ordered correctly).

Notice that although the order of bytes is reversed, each byte has all the bits ordered the same way, so each byte retains it's value.

When a bit-shift occurs, it always occurs according to the machine's byte ordering system, since this is how it's CPU and memory store are designed.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer provides a good sample program. However, I think this sample is a little bit misleading.

The bit string of `1` in little-endian is printed as:

```
10000000|00000000|00000000|00000000
```

I ran this code on my x86 pc and I think the results are reliable. But that doesn't mean that the value `1` is stored as printed above in a little-endian machine.

According to the code of `print_bin`, the num right shifts one bit each time and the **least significant bit** is printed.
Also, the `right shift` operator always shifts from the `most significant bit (MSB)` to the `least significant bit (LSB)`.

In the end, no matter the bit order, the result of `print_bin(1, 4)` is always the reverse of the human-writing bit representation of `1`, which is:

```
00000000|00000000|00000000|00000001
```

For example, the bit string may be:

```
byte significance increase -->
  byte
/-------\
00000001|00000000|00000000|00000000
  |
 bit
<-- bit significance increase
```

In this example, the bit-order is different from the byte-order. But the results of `print_bin(1,4)` would be the same.

**In other words, the printed bit string doesn't necessarily mean reverse bit-order in the little-endian machine.**
I talked about this further in [this blog](https://xinyu-yang.github.io/blog/2023/23-02-01_little-endian/).